# Replace the top fragment on the back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm having so much trouble with Android fragments... Suppose my back stack looks like this

```
[C]
[B]
[A]
---
```

Pressing the back button would pop `Fragment C` off, and leaving `Fragment B` on the top of the stack. Now, how do I swap `Fragment C` for `Fragment D` while maintaining the back stack? Note, `Fragment B` cannot be seen during the operation.

```
[C] <- [D]               [D]
[B]            ----->    [B]
[A]                      [A]
---                      ---
```

This way, pressing the back button would pop `Fragment D` off, and leaving `Fragment B` on top. `Fragment C` is completely removed off the stack.

I add each fragments to the stack like so

```
FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(id, instance, getTag(instance));
ft.addToBackStack(getTag(instance));
ft.commit();
```

I thought this could be achieved by doing the same calls without `addToBackStack`, but it just made `Fragment D` and `Fragment B` overlapped.

Comment: without `addToBackStack`, you transaction remains despite poping the stack, resulting in your D fragment being visible with B

Answer (score 4):

Did you try to pop the back stack before you add fragment D:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.popBackStack(); // or popBackStackImmediate();
ft.addToBackStack(<fragmentD>);
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention `Fragment B` cannot be seen during the operation. Nonetheless, thanks for your input :)

Comment: kind of works, but the backstack is notified, the B fragment is briefly visible. not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

The `fragmentTransaction.replace` supposed to replace all the Fragments in the FragmentManager, and then add the new one.
According to 
[Google](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) :

> This is essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for **all** currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.

But as we see, it isn't always working fine.

(Other useful question about that:
[FragmentTransaction replace not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974173/fragmenttransaction-replace-not-working) )

I use the following code (with the help of `fragmentManager.getFragments()`):

```
int top = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().size()-1;
while (top > 0 && getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(top) == null) {
    top--;
}
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                 .remove(getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(top))
                 .add(R.id.fragment_container, newfrag).commit();
```

(I know I didn't use backstack, but I'm a bit confused with that.)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of time has passed.
I faced the same issue. My solution.

```
    val topFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG)
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    if (topFragment != null) {
            val removeTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
            removeTransaction.remove(currentFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss()
    }
    transaction.add(containerId, newFragment, newFragmentTag)
    transaction.addToBackStack(newFragmentTag)
    transaction.commit()
```